# How to get the 9th Bit from a short

Tags: .net, vb.net, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

Im writing a VB.NET app that reads in bytes. I have a short which contains 2 Bytes received from an outside source.   I now need to get "Bit 8" from the high byte, i cant work out how to do this i can get "bit 1" back as true to tell me if the source is switched on but cant get "bit 8" which i assume is in the second byte.

i've tried

```
Dim bit8 = (p_Value And (1 >> 512 - 1)) <> 0
```

this works for bit 1

```
Dim bit1 = (p_Value And (1 << 1 - 1)) <> 0
```

Document of device gives me

`low byte`

`bit 0 
through to 
bit7`

`High byte`

`bit 8 *the one i want 
through to 
bit 15`

I've searched but everything seems to be for single bytes.

Phil

Comment: could you please rewrite/edit your question? Be clear, help us to help you

Comment: Your bit shifting looks somewhat suspect in the first line.  I'd also recommend potentially using a [`Flags` enum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/what-does-the-flags-enum-attribute-mean-in-c).

Comment: If you're reading bytes, how or why do you end up with int16/short?

Comment: Dim bit8 = (p_Value And (1 << 8)) <> 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with shorts you can use a left shift

```
    Dim shrt As Short = 256S ' bit 8 on

    If (shrt And 1 << 8) <> 0 Then
        Stop
    End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use this function and check the result which will be `True` if the bit is set (`1`) or `False` if the bit is not set (`0`):

```
Function IsBitSet(value As Integer, bit As Integer) As Boolean
    Return ((value And CInt(2 ^ bit)) > 0)
End Function
```

Comment: Curious: would casting a short to an int alter the way this one works?

Comment: @hometoast - no it would just return False for the top order bits

Comment: Exponentiation seems like overkill.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use the BitArray class.  You would then have an array of booleans, one for each bit:

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim value As Short = 123
    Dim ba As New BitArray(BitConverter.GetBytes(value))

    'Get 9th bit.  Bit indexing starts at 0
    Dim bit9 = ba(8)
End Sub
```